# Cabal sandbox on a cloud service

Tags: haskell, cloud, cabal

I'd like to place a cabal sandbox under my Dropbox directory to work there in multiple devices. But cabal stores all package information as absolute paths, which causes link errors when the sandbox's location is different in those devices. Of course it's easy to solve if we try; for example, placing it in the exactly same location in those devices, placing it in an external portable drive, rewriting paths to relative by hand, etc. But, are there any more convenient and intuitive methods? If not, I think there should be one to manage packages on a cloud service that everyone is using nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [sandbox-move](https://github.com/philopon/sandbox-move) yet?

Comment: I've seen and tried this kind of tools, and I know that's another tedious way to list up in the question. I believe we wouldn't like to perform the command every time we switch the device.